# Massive CPU load in VS2015 when double-click-selecting text

Tags: visual-studio-2015

**Context:** Win8.1 Pro x64, freshly installed VS2015 Community Edition with a few common extensions like Productivity Power Tools and ReSharper. Small solution with only one library project and one unit test project, only a handful of source files in total.

**Problem:** When selecting text using doubleclick (to copy and paste some stuff around), every doubleclick increases cpu load by a significant amount (around 10-30%). At first it gets more sluggish with each click, and after a few clicks it reaches 100% and everything hangs for a while until it stabilizes again.

**Measures Taken:** Deactivated various extensions, the only noticeable effect was disabling ReSharper, which decreased the maximum cpu load reached to about 40%. The problem was still present though, so while R# compounds it it does not seem to be the root cause.

Does anyone have experiences with similar issues, or any inkling to what could fix it?

When everything else fails i will try to reinstall VS again, but i am hesitant to do so immediately given the long install process and the fact it is a fresh install.